# Generate seemingly random ascii from input

Tags: javascript, ascii

Given a string of any length (smallish) I need to generate a string of a fixed length that looks random. Running the function on the same input should always result in the same output string.

My first thought was the use the md5 hash of the string. This almost works but even if I encode the result as base 64 the resulting string only contains 0-9 a-z A-Z, I need it to contain symbols as well.

Before someone asks: no, this is not homework.

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: How do you think base64 does it?  Would the same method work for a longer alphabet that included symbols?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat ASCII apparently. It's all the rage these days. You could do something along the lines of: `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));` but that'd only be hex chars...

Comment: Could you turn the input into number (not sure how do do this best without knowing the language), and then use a random number generator with that number as the seed?

Comment: rot13 is the old fashioned way of doing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the input of The Guy with The Hat I came up with the following.

```
Math.seedrandom(input + salt);
var output = "";
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  output += String.fromCharCode (Math.random () * 94 + 33);
```

This code uses [seedrandom.js](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom) to provide a seed for `Math.random ()`.